# Int linked list in c throwing segmentation fault

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, function-definition

Inserting into my linked list is causing a segmentation fault and I'm not sure why. It's an int linked list. It works sometimes and then other times not. I can't see where it would be going wrong? Maybe it has something to do with when I create the new linked list. As the linked list insert last method is working during file reading but not when I create a new list.

```
LinkedList* createLinkedList()
{
    LinkedList* list;

    list = (LinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
    list->length = 0;

    #ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Linked list. Creation of list complete. Checking list length. %d \n", list->length);
    #endif

    return list;
}

void insertLast(LinkedList* list, int entry)
{
    Node* newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data = entry;

    /*If list is empty*/
    if(list->length == 0)
    {
        list->head = newNode;
        list->tail = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        newNode->prev = list->tail;
        /*if this is the second item in the list*/
        if(list->length == 1)
        {
            list->head->next = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            list->tail->next = newNode;
        }
    }
    
    list -> tail = newNode;
    list->length++;
    #ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Linked List. Insert last complete. Checking list length. %d\n", list->length);
    #endif
}
```

This works

```
int main (void)
{
    LinkedList* list = createLinkedList();
    insertLast(list, 1);
}
```

but this doesn't

```
int shortestSeekTimeFirst(LinkedList* list)
{
    LinkedList* usedDisks = createLinkedList();

    int data = list->head->data;
    insertLast(usedDisks, data);
    insertLast(usedDisks, list->head->next->data);
}
```

Comment: maybe linklist in `shortestSeekTimeFirst `,the head is NULL, you cannot get anything from NULL

Comment: Learn to use your environment's debugging tools and step through your code. It will be the best thing for you to do.

Answer (score 5):

You never want to blindly dereference a pointer that could be `NULL`.

In `shortestSeekTimeFirst()` you directly access `list->head->next->data` without checking if any of the pointers are valid, so if any of `list`, `list->head`, or even `list->head->next` is `NULL` your program will segfault.

Answer (score 2):

This function `insertLast` is incorrect.

```
void insertLast(LinkedList* list, int entry)
{
    Node* newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data = entry;

    /*If list is empty*/
    if(list->length == 0)
    {
        list->head = newNode;
        list->tail = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        newNode->prev = list->tail;
        /*if this is the second item in the list*/
        if(list->length == 1)
        {
            list->head->next = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            list->tail->next = newNode;
        }
    }
    
    list -> tail = newNode;
    list->length++;
    #ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Linked List. Insert last complete. Checking list length. %d\n", list->length);
    #endif
}
```

In this if statement

```
    if(list->length == 0)
    {
        list->head = newNode;
        list->tail = newNode;
    }
```

neither the data member `prev` nor the data member `next` of the new node is set to NULL. They are uninitialized and have indeterminate values.

The same problem exists when the list is not empty that is neither the data member `prev` nor the data member `next` of the new node is set.

The function can be written simpler

```
 int insertLast( LinkedList *list, int entry )
 {
     Node* newNode = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
     int success = newNode != NULL;

     if ( success )
     {
         newNode->data = entry;
         newNode->next = NULL;
         newNode->prev = list->tail;

         if ( list->tail == NULL )
         {
             list->head = newNode;
         }
         else
         {
             list->tail->next = newNode;
         }  

         list->tail = newNode; 
         list->length++;
     }

     return success;
 }
```

As for this code snippet

```
int shortestSeekTimeFirst(LinkedList* list)
{
    LinkedList* usedDisks = createLinkedList();

    int data = list->head->data;
    insertLast(usedDisks, data);
    insertLast(usedDisks, list->head->next->data);
}
```

then after this declaration

```
    LinkedList* usedDisks = createLinkedList();
```

the data members head and tail of the list are equal to NULL. So at least this
statement

```
    int data = list->head->data;
```

invokes undefined behavior.